# ASP.NET Soap Webservice Implicit "Out" Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm in the process of modernizing one of my company's older websites. As a part of this process, I need to change a few calls to the webservices we host.

I'm a bit new to WCF programming, and I understand that there is an "old way" and a "new way" of working with these services. The old version of our site made calls to them the old way, and I'm trying to update them to the new way. I don't understand the structure of it beyond that.

The main issue that I'm seeing is that, at the end of some of our service calls, we have two "out" parameters. For example, the call to our PayPal webservice has

```
out processPayPalCCTestResult, out processPayPalCCTestResultSpecified
```

both of which are boolean. I understand out parameters in general, but I thought the practice of using them was discouraged from a design perspective.

These two parameters do not appear in the definition of the webservice, and Visual Studios throws a "no overloaded version takes in this many parameters" error. I assume, then, that these parameters are an architectural feature of WCF that I am unaware of. What do these parameters signify, and how can I make Visual Studios aware of their existence? Or is it simply impossible using the "new way" of interacting with WCF?

Comment: Why you want to use these as output parameters, normally you will have in parameters an a result of the call, the result could be an object with all the information that you need.

Comment: That would make the most sense to me as well. Unfortunately, some of the legacy code relies on these out's, and removing them will require a modification of the webservices themselves. I plan to do that, but I have to convince management it's worth the time first.

Comment: Maybe you could add a Wrapper over the WCF Client call, returning the result and set this to the output parameters on the Wrapper.